# Swift accessing response from function

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am producing a GET request, which gives me JSON object of array within dictionaries in this format:

```
Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
```

I have a class:

```
class foodMenu: UITableViewController{

    var jsonData:Array<Dictionary<String,String>>! // Here is set an empty global variable(Not sure if I am doing this right either)

    func getFoodRequest(){
        Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_food").responseJSON {
            response in
            print("This response", response.result)
            let result = response.result.value
            self.jsonData = result as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
        }
   }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   getFoodRequest()        
   return jsonData!.count
  }   
}
```

jsonData returns nil. My goal is to  have an array of `jsonData` so i can use .count method on it.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is probably being called long before `getFoodRequest` is being called.

Comment: I tried calling getFoodRequest() in viewDidLoad then tried printing the statement after; doest getFoodRequest get executed first then following print statement.

Comment: Yeah but the Alamofire request is asynchronous. `self.jsonData` will be set later on after the request completes.

Comment: You might want to use a Promise library

Comment: I've updated the thread. I'm trying to access my global variable in my tableView.

Comment: `jsonData` is not a global and it is not a closure, so what is this question even about?

Comment: Also you have _defined_ `getFoodRequest` but you have never _called_ it, so what on earth would cause `jsonData` to have any value? Your question makes no sense. An uncalled function does nothing.

Comment: I had the wrong idea about 'closure'. I reworded my question @matt sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Please do a search on "asynchronous". This question has been answer zillions of times here already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to network synchronously, and you can't. Actually, you are networking asynchronously, which is correct, but you are forgetting that networking is asynchronous.

Let's look at your code:

```
func getFoodRequest(){
    Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_food").responseJSON {
        response in
        let result = response.result.value
        self.jsonData = result as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>> // B
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    getFoodRequest() // A      
    return jsonData!.count // C
}
```

Look at the letter comments I've added. You seem to think that the code executes in the order A,B,C. It doesn't. It executes in the order A,C,B. That's because getting your response *takes time* and happens on a background thread, and meanwhile your `numberOfRowsInSection` has gone right ahead and executed the next line and finished.